# Disable Close button of window - VSTO - Outlook

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, office-addins

I need to disable the close window button in a specific case, but I don't know how to do it. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box. You may try using Windows API functions to subclass Outlook windows, but this is not really a supported scenario - you do everything on your own risk. See [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) for more information.